# Elastic Beanstalk Thinks Environment is Not Running

Tags: amazon-web-services, push, config, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I try to do an aws.push from the command line I get an "environment is not running error" though my amazon.com console shows the status is green and my hosted sites all appear to be functional.

I don't want to lose the instance because I spent a lot of time customizing it to run various php and node sites using vhosts and everything seems to be functional anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by running eb init again with new security credentials